# iTunes Connect says "ready for upload". When trying to validate in Xcode, it says the app should be ready to upload in iTunes Connect

Tags: xcode, validation, submit, app-store-connect

Sorry for the long title. It basically summarizes what I'm trying to ask. I set up my app to be ready for upload in iTunes Connect, and when I'm trying to "Validate" the app in Xcode, it says I need to have the app prepared in iTunes Connect.

Here is what I see in iTunes Connect:

- Buttons The Game

  Version 1.0

  Copyright Nimish Upadhyay (AweShowSome)

  Primary Category Games

  Subcategory Puzzle

  Subcategory Board

  Secondary Category (Optional)

  Rating 4+

  **Status  Prepare for Upload**

Here is what I see in Xcode when trying to validate:

- Applications must be ready for upload on iTunes Connect before they
  can be validated or submitted from within Xcode.

Please answer my question, this is my first app. If you can also, could you also tell me the next steps on how to submit an app after validation. Just don't send me the ios developing help guide. Thanks.

Comment: I can see two possible problems.  The first is if you are using a different username and password for setting up the app and validating it.  That's simple, I know, but that would cause this problem.  The second is if you didn't click the button "Ready to Upload Binary" inside iTunes connect.  I missed it the first time.  When you "Manage your apps" in iTunes connect and then click on your app there is a button in the top right that says "Ready to Upload Binary."

Comment: Also want to make sure that your bundle IDs match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this it works

It's because your App is on 'Prepare for Upload' state. You have to change its state to 'Ready to Upload Binary' by clicking the following button on your app page, on itunesconnect. It's on the right corner.[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Here is what you need to take care of :**

- Ensure that an app record exists for your app in iTunes Connect.
- Ensure that the app record status is at least “Waiting to Upload.”

**In your case**, first you need to tap on Ready to upload Binary, fill out cryptography page. App status will automatically become “Waiting to Upload.”
For further reference : [Validating Your App](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-archives_organizer/articles/validating_apps.html)